# java- How would you sort an Integer type array of length 3 where the last index is the middle value?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, while-loop

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[3];
array[0] = 3;
```

Given a value to insert into the array.

I believe it will be similar to insertion sort utilizing 
-a while loop and and an 
-if statement

- the last index is the middle value of index [0] & [1] ([0]<[2]<[1])
- The array's length is 3.
- An integer will by default be in the array[0] index.

ex. of properly sorted arrays 
(1,3,2)
, (5,10,8)

### step #1)

- If there is only 1 value in the array all that is needed is to compare the valueToInsert and the value in the array.

valueToInsert = 3

(0, null, null)--> (0,3, null)

### step#2)

- If there are 2 values in the array must compare valueToInsert against the two values in the array and place in correct position.
- valueToInsert can 1. only be placed [0] (if less than [0]), 2. placed in[1](if greater than[1], 3. placed in [2](if greater than[0] and less than [1]

valueToInsert = 2

(0,3,null) --> (0,3,2)

How would this be implemented?

Comment: `Arrays.sort(arr); swap(arr, 1, 2);`

Comment: what do you mean by last index is middle value?

Comment: Why are you "inserting" values in the array? Show an example please, because arrays have a fixed length; and you appeared to ask about sorting...

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I edited my question. Thanks for the quick responses though.

Comment: I'm inserting an int value into the array so i can sort them. I'm given an array with 1 value in the [0] index, and must insert a value 'x'. If there is only 1 value in the array I only compare the value in[0] and the value to be inserted. If there are 2 keys (Ex. (1,3,null)) the value to be inserted must be inserted into the correct position.

Comment: You can't store `null` in an `int[]`. Please post example **code**. Your notation is not clear.

Comment: It's an Integer[] array not an int[] array. Sorry for the confusion. I don't have much code that will be clear. Sorry.

Comment: How can there be only 1 or 2 elements in an array of 3 elements? Do you mean 'last *element* is middle value'? Are you trying to sort, or trying to achieve the condition?

Answer (score 0):

If there are only 3 elements, you don't need to loop it.

Assuming 3 variables `a`,`b` & `c` hold the array elements `0`,`1` & `2`:

```
int a=arr[0], b=arr[1], c=arr[2];
```

To sort it:

```
arr[0] = Math.min(Math.min(a, b), c);
arr[1] = Math.max(Math.max(a, b), c);
arr[2] = (a+b+c) - (arr[0] + arr[1]);
```